# PUB-SUB with INPROC transport could not receive messages

Tags: zeromq, inproc

I have an issue using ZMQ inproc with PUB-SUB, where the first message is not read by a subscriber. I am sure I am doing something wrong / misread the documentation in some part.

I have 2 pubs and 2 subs, communicating via inproc (in a 1 to 1 fashion) sequentially in the same thread. The use case come from a unit test, but AFAIU inproc should be synchronous and usable in this way.

I attach the example code.

```
#include <zmq.h>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new();

    void *write_socket_srv = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);
    assert(write_socket_srv != nullptr);
    void *read_socket_srv = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    assert(read_socket_srv != nullptr);

    void *write_socket_clt = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);
    assert(write_socket_clt != nullptr);
    void *read_socket_clt = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    assert(read_socket_clt != nullptr);

    std::string endpoint1 = "inproc:///test_endpoint1";
    std::string endpoint2 = "inproc:///test_endpoint2";

    assert(zmq_bind(write_socket_srv, endpoint1.c_str()) == 0);
    assert(zmq_connect(read_socket_clt, endpoint1.c_str()) == 0);

    assert(zmq_bind(read_socket_srv, endpoint2.c_str()) == 0);
    assert(zmq_connect(write_socket_clt, endpoint2.c_str()) == 0);

    // Some options.
    int optionValue = 1;
    // Write: set conflate.
    zmq_setsockopt(write_socket_srv, ZMQ_CONFLATE, &optionValue, sizeof(int));
    zmq_setsockopt(write_socket_clt, ZMQ_CONFLATE, &optionValue, sizeof(int));

    // Read: set conflate and subscribe.
    zmq_setsockopt(read_socket_srv, ZMQ_CONFLATE, &optionValue, sizeof(int));
    zmq_setsockopt(read_socket_srv, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);
    zmq_setsockopt(read_socket_clt, ZMQ_CONFLATE, &optionValue, sizeof(int));
    zmq_setsockopt(read_socket_clt, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);

    const std::string message1 = "this is a message";
    std::size_t message_size1 = message1.size() * sizeof(std::string::value_type);

    const std::string message2 = "this is a second message";
    std::size_t message_size2 = message2.size() * sizeof(std::string::value_type);

    std::byte read_buffer1[128];
    std::byte read_buffer2[128];

    // <<<<<<<>>>>>>>
    // I need to call this recv, even if I know there is nothing, otherwise the following
    // reads won't work!
    zmq_recv(read_socket_srv, read_buffer1, 128, ZMQ_DONTWAIT);

    // srv sends to clt
    assert(zmq_send(write_socket_srv, message1.data(), message_size1, 0) ==
           message_size1);

    int bytes_read2 = zmq_recv(read_socket_clt, read_buffer2, 128, 0);
    assert(bytes_read2 > 0);

    // clt sends to srv
    assert(zmq_send(write_socket_clt, message2.data(), message_size2, 0) ==
           message_size2);

    int bytes_read1 = zmq_recv(read_socket_srv, read_buffer1, 128, 0);
    assert(bytes_read1 > 0);

    // Assuming the encoding is correct:
    const char *buffer_as_str = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(read_buffer1);
    std::string read_message(buffer_as_str, buffer_as_str + bytes_read1);

    assert(read_message == message2);
    assert(bytes_read1 == message_size2);
    std::cout << "read_socket_srv read \"" << read_message << "\"\n";

    buffer_as_str = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(read_buffer2);
    read_message = std::string(buffer_as_str, buffer_as_str + bytes_read2);

    assert(read_message == message1);
    assert(bytes_read2 == message_size1);
    std::cout << "read_socket_clt read \"" << read_message << "\"\n";

    assert(zmq_unbind(write_socket_srv, endpoint1.c_str()) == 0);
    assert(zmq_disconnect(read_socket_clt, endpoint1.c_str()) == 0);

    assert(zmq_unbind(read_socket_srv, endpoint2.c_str()) == 0);
    assert(zmq_disconnect(write_socket_clt, endpoint2.c_str()) == 0);

    zmq_close(read_socket_srv);
    zmq_close(write_socket_clt);
    zmq_close(write_socket_srv);
    zmq_close(read_socket_clt);

    assert(zmq_ctx_term(context) == 0);
    return 0;
}
```

This example, as is, works. But if I comment the first recv (which is not needed as there are no messages) the following `recv` blocks forever waiting for messages.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I did a couple of additional tests:

1. splitting in 2 binaries and using `ipc` or `tcp` (in a while true + sleep) as expected works perfectly.
2. More interesting: still `inproc`, I tried reordering the calls, and.. it is always the `recv` on `read_socket_srv` that is causing issues. I can't see any pattern but this can't be a coincidence

Answer (score 0):

ZeroMQ normally creates some [background threads](http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-ctx-set#toc4) to handle I/O operations.

The in-process transport is intended for use *between threads*. Because you should already have two threads, ZeroMQ does not use these background threads for the in-process transport.

> No I/O threads are involved in passing messages using the inproc transport. Therefore, if you are using a ØMQ context for in-process messaging only you can initialise the context with zero I/O threads.[*](http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-inproc)

When you use the in-process transport from a single thread, communication stalls because you cannot both send and receive in the same thread.

Comment: So is this WAI? So there is no way to reliably communicate in the same thread in a synchronous way? (The use case is tests, not a real application of course). Why once the first recv is called, everything else then "just work"?

Comment: It is not supported. If it works under certain circumstances, that is just luck. Why not use a thread in your tests?

Comment: Because in general threads add uncertainties, timing and synchronisation issues. Clearly if this is not supported I will need to add this, but I was hoping that given the use case this was supported. Thanks for your response